# how do I get a my cli app to move on to the next method?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, command-line-interface

(using tty-prompt) I've tried making individual methods so that my app can run smoothly however I only managed to break my code or set it into a infinite prompt..I've been stuck trying to set up activerecord CRUD

I made new method for each prompt

```
def greet
  $prompt = TTY::Prompt.new
  system "clear"

  puts 'Welcome to gig_finder, the best resource for finding your next gig!'
end

def user
  name = $prompt.ask('What is your name?', default: "artist_name")
  system "clear"
  puts "Welcome #{user}!"
end
```

the output would continue to ask for a name, until you force quit

Comment: Can you include the code where these methods are called?

Comment: yes, the methods are being called in a run.rb file (calling: greet, then user, etc.)that requires the environment, and the environment requires all files in a lib dir

Comment: can you show the run.rb please?

Comment: ```endP = true
greet
user
while endP
venue_selection
endP = book
end     ```

Comment: Place your run.rb code in the question itself, please.  Your question should be self-contained, and include everything needed for others to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because in your `user` method you call the `user` method again.

```
def user   # <--- user
  name = $prompt.ask('What is your name?', default: "artist_name")
  system "clear"
  puts "Welcome #{user}!"  # <--- calls user
end
```

This causes an infinite loop.

You probably meant to use:

```
  puts "Welcome #{name}!"
```